# How to configure vim to save extra copies

Tags: linux, vim, backup

Is there a way to configure vim so that, instead of creating a temporary `.swp`, every time a save is made, suppose that I'm editing the file `name_of_the_file.txt`, the program automatically creates a file containing the previous save, named with the data and time of the saving, e.g. `name_of_the_file-05-17-2017-11:20.txt` in a folder, let say `~/.vim-bckp/name_of_the_file/`? Or, better, having a custom command for saving that do the above request and avoid flooding the HDD with minor changes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will do the trick. You could name it vimBackup or anything, do not use existing commands name. Then you could copy the command somewhere into the paths in $PATH variable or append $PATH variable with a custom script folder containing this script. Then you able to use it without using the full path to execute it.

```
#!/bin/sh

[[ $1 == "" ]] && echo "Command expect a file path" && exit 1
[[ ! $# == 1 ]] && echo "Command expect only one parameter" && exit 1
[[ -w $1 ]] && cp $1 $1_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M) # if exist and writable make a copy
vim $1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written the [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828) for that. That turned into a full plugin suite:

- The [writebackupVersionControl plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1829) plugin complements this script with additional commands and enhances the `:WriteBackup` command with more checks, but is not required.
- The [writebackupToAdjacentDir plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3107) implements a WriteBackup-dynamic-backupdir configuration that puts the backup files in an adjacent backup directory if one exists. This helps where the backups cannot be placed into the same directory.
- The [writebackupAutomator plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3940) automatically writes a backup on a day's first write of a file that was backed up in the past, but not yet today. It can be your safety net when you forget to make a backup.

So, once I have made a backup, I don't need to think about explicitly triggering one. I can view diffs, and even restore previous versions. Of course, if you can use a "full" version control system (like Git or Subversion), use that. But this one is nice for all the little configuration changed distributed throughout the file system.